# I am new to Django can anyone help me with the below task....?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Go through the sample JSON file given here -
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xZa3UoXZ3uj2j0Q7653iBp1NrT0gKj0Y
This JSON file describes a list of users & their corresponding periods of activity across
multiple months.
Now, design and implement a Django application with User and ActivityPeriod models, write
a custom management command to populate the database with some dummy data and design
an API to serve that data in the JSON format given above.

Comment: Please do not add a link to your code, instead add the code in your "```" code with these around it

Answer (score 1):

To build the application with the mentioned requirements you need to have at least a basic understanding of the Django and Django rest framework. There are plenty of learning materials on the web to get started. Mozilla has a very good tutorial to get begin with. Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django
Similarly, For the REST API, there are free videos on YouTube offered by channels such as Dennis Ivy's, CodingEntrepreneurs which are good to get started with. I would recommend you to check those videos!
All the best!
Happy Coding